# If I bind TwoWay to DataRow[i], should the DataTable be updated automatically? WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently writing my first WPF application. I have the content of a database table in a DataTable. Now I want to bind each value of a DataRow TwoWay to the ContentProperty of a button.

If I click the button, the value of ContentProperty is changed, but the source doesn't update. What am I missing here?

My Code in the Codebehind:

```
Binding binding = new Binding(".")
{
    Source = dataRowKalender[i],
    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
};
button.SetBinding(ContentProperty, binding);


private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    btn = (Button)sender;
    if ((string)btn.Content == "ITS")
        btn.Content = "Praktikum";
    else if ((string)btn.Content == "Praktikum")
        btn.Content = "ITS";
}
```

Comment: Aren't tuples readonly?

Comment: Yes, but the saving of the data from DataTable to database works. The only problem is that the source (DataTable) doesn't update.

Comment: Sounds like a very bad idea to me to bind to an index, why not bind your master control on the dataRowKalender completely and use the Item viewer? It seems to me that you are also missing views, which sounds a lot better as a general approach to binding

Comment: @Icepickle Could you please specify what you mean with views? DataRowView?

Comment: No, I was rather thinking about [MVVM](http://www.markwithall.com/programming/2013/03/01/worlds-simplest-csharp-wpf-mvvm-example.html) with wpf

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as below and check, I guess you are missing Path property.

```
Binding binding = new Binding()
{
    Source = this,
    Path = new PropertyPath("dataRowKalender[i]"),
    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
};
button.SetBinding(ContentProperty, binding);
```

this should work. cheers

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it shows this error: (translated from german) The type "object" can not be implicitly converted to "System.Windows.PropertyPath". There is already an explicit conversion (possibly missing a conversion)

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't solve the problem. Now it doesn't even show the Content in the button.

Comment: I've tried `Path = new PropertyPath(dataRowKalender[i])` but now I get an exception: "Object "System.String" can not be used as Accessor-Parameter for a PropertyPath. An Accessor-Parameter must be "DependencyProperty", "PropertyInfo" or "PropertyDescriptor""

Comment: the above code will work if dataRowKalender was just a string. But since you are trying to access with index(dataRowKalender[i]), it is not working.

Comment: I got a solution, make access specifier of dataRowKalender to public.
for example public List<string> dataRowKalender {get;}// i have just assumed it as a List it can be any datatype.